# Google Map Icon Placement

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get my custom icon placed to have the bottom of the pin on the coordinate like so:

[[image: 1]]

I know the coords (in this case for Alexandria) are correct as tested [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/31%C2%B000'47.6%22N+29%C2%B047'58.0%22E/@26.7651928,34.8020133,6.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d31.013217!4d29.799444).

I call the Marker constructor like so:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: Number(markerData.geodata.lat), lng: Number(markerData.geodata.lng)},
    title: '',
    icon: { 
        url: _config.static.marker.default.normal.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(3, 3, 'rem', 'rem'),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(3, 3, 'rem', 'rem'),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0) <-- I think this is where I'm going wrong
    },
    type: t,
    continent: markerData.continent,
    country: markerData.country,
    id: id,
    labelTitle: markerData.name,
    label: markerData.name.constructor,
    labelClass: 'map-marker-label map-marker-label-village',
    zIndex: 1
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you actually find where you made a mistake, anchor are the coordinates of the point in your image where the lat/lng coordinates are.

So if you want the bottom of the pin to be on the lat/lng coordinates, you should put anchor at the image coordinates X/Y of the pixel at the bottom of the pin.

In your case it will be :

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(27, 54)
```

because you want it at the bottom's middle